# How would I calculate the price of an item given the supply and the demand of it

Tags: statistics

I don't know if this should go on stack overflow, but this problem that I'm having is primarily a math one. I'm wanting to build a dynamic market for well minecraft as a plugin, but ignore that as the problem is that I need to know how to calculate a price of an item, if I have the supply and the demand, but don't have an inherent value of the item. I can't really find any good resources on it, so can someone give me an answer or direct me to some resources that could help me

Comment: You set a starting price, and the market corrects it. Kind of like an IPO. It's based on how much an "expert" valuates something. For real physical items it's easier, since it has a cost to produce, plus a desired profit.

Comment: Alright I'll look into it, my idea is something similar to Eve Online's market.